# JavaScript to read local file

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to enable native JavaScript to read local file on the disk?

no Ajax, no JQuery or other JavaScript library, only use the native JavaScript?

I have searched, but it seems there is no way to do this.

My requirements are that when the Internet can not be accessed, I will show a warning page in the Chrome browser.

Comment: what about HTML5 Filereader API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5, have a File Api, if you are interested in reading file, just for the reading - [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), [HTML5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

If you are more interested in the case when the user is [offline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events), and your application needs a storage, you can take a look at localstorage - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), [diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). There is an example how to check if it is available, although [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage) says it is currently available everywhere. Here is a live [example](http://html5demos.com/storage).

Hope this will help, in your case which seems to be the synchronization after being offline.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaScript in a browser, there is no way to access an arbitrary file from the local filesystem like this. `XMLHTTPRequest` can be used to access files natively without a library like jQuery, but it prevents access to local files as a security measure.

However, you can use a [`cache.manifest`](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) file to set up an offline version of an HTML 5 site/app.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `<input type="file"/>` and Javascript's `window.FileReader` to read file. It has many methods of receiving the data, easiest being `FileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);` You can only read files that a user has selected from a file browser.

[Here's Mozilla Developer Network's documentation on it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

For your uses, however, it seems like developing a Chrome extension would be a better solution to manipulating the way Google Chrome works.